# How can I get the last value of an array?

Tags: php

Below are the contents of the array. How can I get the last array, `[cat_name] => Lcd`?

I do not need:

```
[cat_link] => lcd 
[cat_id] => 172
```

---

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => Electronics
            [cat_link] => electronics
            [cat_id] => 164
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => Televisions
            [cat_link] => televisions
            [cat_id] => 165
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => Lcd
            [cat_link] => lcd
            [cat_id] => 172
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last `cat_name` value like so:

```
$arr[count($arr) - 1]['cat_name']
```

Comment: @baris22: PHP 5.2 and lower have this odd quirk where `[` cannot follow `)`. So `end($arr)['cat_name']` would be a syntax error. Just FYI :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php).

```
$lastMember = end($arr);
```

Note that this advances the array's internal pointer, which may matter dependent on what other code you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the last element of the array like this: `$array[count($array) - 1]`